# Create an AppBarIcon Image

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Dev05(which just released).

In the documentation the icon looks like this `icon: Image,` but in Android Studio 
the icon is of type Painter(which was added in Dev05) `icon: Painter,`.

How would I convert an image to this new Painter type? Or am I missing something completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ImagePainter()` and pass in the `image`.

something like this,

```
val image = ImagePainter(imageResource(R.drawable.YOUR-IMAGE))

 AppBarIcon(image, onClick = {
       //Do something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With `1.0.0-beta02` you can use:

```
val image = Image(painterResource(id = R.drawable.xxx),"contentDescription")
```